# Fetch attachment content using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail to automate some email handling.

I managed to get a connection to the pop3 server and fetch the messages. Some of them contains an attachment. Base on the email title I am able to "predict" the filename of the attachment that I need to fetch.

But I can't get its content :(

I have a function

```
public byte[] searchForContent(Part part,String fileName){
    if(part.getFileName()!=null){
        if(part.getFileName().equals(fileName)){
            byte[] content = new byte[part.getSize()];
            part.getInputStream().read(content);
            return content[]
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The function works very well (ie: return content only if the part was the attachment described by fileName). But the array its returns is too big.

The downloaded attachment is 256 bytes long and the function return a 352 bytes long content.

I think that the problem comes from the headers, but I can't be sure.

How would you proceed to get the content only ?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean too big? does it create the specified file? If so, then how can it be too big

Comment: If I download the attachment on my desktop and check the size, I get 256 bytes. But for the same attachment, when I run this code, the returned array is 352 bytes long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

As eaj told : part.getSize() returns the size of the part object. Not the size of the attachment itself.

However the InputStream returned by part.getInputStream() contains the content of the attachment only.

So the code below does give the expected result :

```
public byte[] searchForContent(Part part,String fileName){
    if(part.getFileName()!=null){
        if(part.getFileName().equals(fileName)){
            InputStream stream=part.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer) != -1)
            {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the API documentation for `javax.mail.Part.getSize()` says

> Note that the size may not be an exact measure of the content size and may or may not account for any transfer encoding of the content. The size is appropriate for display in a user interface to give the user a rough idea of the size of this part.

Assuming that you know the type of content, you can probably fetch it from `Part.getContent()` and process that.  `getContent()` returns an Object, but if you know the content type you can cast it appropriately (e.g. to a String for text).